# How to add package icon into arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

How to get the application icon that i got from the result into arraylist?

If i use
`attrs.icon("Package Name", pkg.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager()));`

it show this error
**The method icon(String, Drawable) is undefined for the type Map**

if i use
`attrs.put("Package Name", pkg.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager()));`

it show this error
**The method put(String, String) in the type Map is not applicable for the arguments (String, Drawable)**

**i have tried**

`Drawable icon;`

`attrs.icon("Package Name", pkg.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager()));`

`Drawable Icon = pm.getApplicationIcon(pkg.applicationInfo);`

all giving error on eclipse

Here's the code

```
protected void onPostExecute(List < PackageInfo > result) {

    // Here you will have all the setAdapter related code
    List < PackageInfo > adPackages = result;
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

    List < Map < String, String >> data = new ArrayList < Map < String, String >> (
    adPackages.size());

    for (PackageInfo pkg: adPackages) {
        Map < String, String > attrs = new HashMap < String, String > ();

        attrs.put("App Name", pm.getApplicationLabel(pkg.applicationInfo).toString());
        attrs.put("Package Name", pkg.packageName);
        //Drawable icon;
        //attrs.icon("Package Name", pkg.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager()));
        // Drawable Icon = pm.getApplicationIcon(pkg.applicationInfo);
        data.add(attrs);

    }

    String[] from = new String[] {
        "App Name", "Package Name"
    };
    int[] to = new int[] {
        R.id.text1, R.id.text2
    };
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
    AppsInspectorActivity.this, data, R.layout.two_line_list_item, from, to);

    ListView mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.l_list);

    mList.setAdapter(adapter);
    mPackages = adPackages;

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attrs` is a Map so it doesn't have a method called "icon". You need to just do `attrs.put("icon",pkg.applicationInfo.icon+"");`
the `+""` is there because pkg.applicationInfo.icon is an integer so you need to convert it to a String before you can put it into a map parameterized with

Comment: Thanks it works but when i switch to `attrs.put("Icon",pkg.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager())+"");` it show empty icon , am i missing something?

Comment: Your attrs map is defined such that it can only hold strings as values (so you can't load an icon and store it in that map).Unlike integers, you can't simply add "" to an image to convert it to a string.